# Terminal flickers transparent in Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, unity, nvidia, gnome

My terminal is configured to the default settings in Ubuntu. That is to say: **It should not be transparent**. And most of the time it isn't...

[image: Shadow image of Firefox behind terminal]

From time to time an application will become semi-transparent. This transparency will dissipate if I select the window, or even hover over it, and it often becomes more/less transparent as other things on my screen change.

For example, if my input selector is flashing in a different terminal, the offending terminal window will transition between about 10% transparency and 25% transparency.

Is this a problem with my drivers? They're up to date:

```
apt search nvidia-driver
...
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430/bionic,now 430.26-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Is this a problem with my window display system, or a known issue with Ubuntu, Nvidia, Gnome-shell, or what?

This has been happening for weeks. Please help.

[Related Ubuntu bug from 2010. This is still open now.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/561370)

> GP107GL [Quadro P400]
>   NVIDIA Driver Version: 430.26

Comment: This solved it for me: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1726262/comments/13

Comment: Great write-up.  I have an nvidia card and my terminal window will flash and become semi-transparent when other windows open. But if you click in the terminal window then it becomes 100% opaque.

Answer (score 3):

My Terminal window was flashing (fading in/out from transparency quickly) each time it thought the window was getting focus.  It would flash in the background as I worked in other windows.  Really annoying.

From your terminal window...

1. select the Edit...Preferences... menu item
2. select the Colors tab
3. uncheck the "Use transparency from system theme" (shown checked below)

This fixed mine.
[image: preferences...colors]